# Pie Chart keeps loading and never stops

Tags: highcharts, rally

I'm currently working on implementing a drop down filter on my pie chart that will reload the pie chart with the appropriate results after selecting an item on the drop down. However, the problem I'm running into, is that once I select a filterable item, the chart reloads-- but it stays "loading" forever.

I'm not too experienced in working with highcharts, but does anyone have an idea of what could be making it stay in this state forever?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running into a well-known defect with the Rally.ui.chart.Chart component.  You can work around this by turning off the load mask on the chart.

Check out the [loadMask](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.chart.Chart-cfg-loadMask) property.

```
var config = {
    loadMask: false
};
```